# Why is FreeRTOS windows demo failing when creating the IDLE task?

Tags: freertos

I'm starting with FreeRTOS and I'm trying to debug the Windows Demo. It compiles just fine but when I'm stepping in the code I can see that the **assert** inside the **xTaskGenericCreate** is being generated when FreeRTOS is trying to create the idle task.

I don't know why this is hapening since I haven't modified the original demo code.

Could anyone help me with this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you could say which assert was hit I could probably tell you right away what the issue is.

Is this the Windows project form the main FreeRTOS kernel download?  Is it the Visual Studio or MingW/Eclipse version (https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html)?  Did you make any changes at all, even if you think they are minor?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not using windows anymore. I tried a couple more things I don't remember that didn't work either and then life took me to ditch Windows and start using Linux as my OS so I guess this question will remain unanswered forever.